# Redmi Note 5 pro: No more app icon view in recent app screen?

Tags: android, mi

Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro not showing app icon recent apps. see image and i expect result like Skype icon.

See this image and different my application icon and Skype application icon.

[image]

Comment: can you mention android manifest code?

Comment: which type code mention ? @Abhinav Gupta

Comment: I am facing this issue too in MOTO android P device(Stock android) for all apps not particularly a debug app. I thought its a BUG .

Comment: do you have any default app icon in mipmap-v26 etc folders ,if yes then delete them

Comment: If you are using an SVG it might not show up there. I too have an error, resolved by using a png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match your manifest application tag with below tags.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

//other code

</application>
```

Also use png for app icon.